# HyperLedger Sawtooth Seth Getting Started error 2

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I'm following the Getting started tutorial of Sawtooth Seth (https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/seth/releases/latest/getting_started.html), but I'm not able to set up an account on the network. The network is running properly in another shell. (I've removed the -aes128 flag for simplicity)

```
 lorenzo@MacBook-Air-di-Lorenzo ~ $ cd gitHubRepo/sawtooth-seth/
 lorenzo@MacBook-Air-di-Lorenzo ~/gitHubRepo/sawtooth-seth $ docker exec -it seth-cli bash
 root@a6caea38a1a8:/project/sawtooth-seth# openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 | openssl ec -out key-file.pem      

 read EC key
 writing EC key

 root@a6caea38a1a8:/project/sawtooth-seth# seth account import key-file.pem myalias

 error: Found argument 'myalias' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
USAGE:
seth account import <key-file> --pass-file <pass-file>
For more information try --help

root@a6caea38a1a8:/project/sawtooth-seth# seth account import key-file.pem --pass-file myalias

Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)

root@a6caea38a1a8:/project/sawtooth-seth# ls

bin  cli  common  contracts  key-file.pem  protos  tests
```

Answer (score 1):

You ran the `seth` command in the `seth-cli` Docker container.
You need to run it in the `seth-cli-go` container until PR https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-seth/pull/72 is merged.
EDIT: This was merged 2018-11-13.

A good resource for questions like this is also the seth chat channel at
https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/sawtooth-seth